# Customize xdg-open to open home page without URL

Tags: command-line, default-browser, url

Is it possible to somehow use the xdg-open command to open my home page (google.com) without having to type the url.

What i mean to say is, can i customize

```
xdg-open http://www.google.com
```

to something like:

```
xdg-open myhome
```

to open it?

Comment: Why not just run `firefox`, or `google-chrome`, or whatever browser you want to open?

Comment: @EricCarvalho: i feel its much easier this way. The answer below is useful. Just typing "myhome" in the command line is much easier than switching to GUI and then opening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an alias for your shell. Add this to your .bashrc (assuming you use bash):

```
alias myhome='xdg-open http://www.google.com'
```

Then call it with `myhome`

Or define it as a variable (in .bashrc):

```
myhome='http://www.google.com'
```

And call with `xdg-open $myhome`

Though as mentioned in the comments, if google.com is the start page in your browser just call your browser from the command-line, f.ex.:

```
google-chrome &
firefox &
```

You probably want the `&` at the end to open it in the background.